# ECDSA signature

Tags: c#, cryptography, win-universal-app

I have a problem during sign a message with ECDSA algorithm; I think ECDSA signature has a standard format, beginning with 0x30 and following by signature length, as you can see in online ECDSA signature generation, https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample-ecdsa.html. I am using the following code but I don't receive a valid ECDSA signature form.

```
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider _objAlgProv = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.EcdsaSha256);
string _StrMessage = "0055673B5138CC90D3B7F32BFDAD6A38A8EDD7B355B77AB9792196F106D16CA312049500D67477BAC1B959063726F3A8A43AA7FD068CA775C502213C0732B2ECC836B3906DB0E2D3F9CA06BA54570DB41DBDD6C49E2BAF8BECFF47B176E64983A5049500D67477BAC1B959063726F3A8A43AA7FD068CA775C502213C0732B2ECC804D7985513A5B89452FBC15FE656258062403BC0CCF619A656840AD5DF5D55B4A3FB8B1BA93577BAAD063B381E56084A655D3F2AFE85BE08C6DBA94FE651BFB435";
IBuffer _IMessage = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromHexString(_StrMessage);
CryptographicKey __KeyPair = _objAlgProv.CreateKeyPairWithCurveName(EccCurveNames.SecP256r1);
IBuffer __ISign = await CryptographicEngine.SignAsync(__KeyPair, _IMessage);
byte[] __ByteSign = { 0 };
CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(__ISign, out __ByteSign);
```

I also have generated the ECDSA signature using OpenSSL in C++ and always I have a unique valid ECDSA signature format, beginning with 0x30. I don't know what is the problem with ECDSA algorithms in Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core namespace in windows universal.

Comment: You don't get a valid ECDSA signature, right? What do you get then?

Comment: Let me guess, you get 64 bytes as output?